# SSH Agent Forwarding on AWS NAT Gateway

Tags: ssh, nat, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I know that it's possible to configure SSH Agent forwarding on Bastion Instance and NAT Instance. Is it possible to do this on NAT Gateway as well?

Answer (score 2):

NAT Gateway is a managed service - AWS will not provide console or any other access to server. It responsible only to perform Network Address Translation (NAT). To reach instance in NATed subnets you will need to create a separate bastion host in external segment.